# Cannot find google apps script for mynewfunction

Tags: locate

I received an email from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com entitled "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: mynewfunction" that informs me that ny script mynewfunction is not working. I wrote the code many years ago as a test and now it has re-emerged as problematic according to a recent deluge of emails.

I went to my dashboard  at https://script.google.com/home/all expecting to see the errant script so that I could either troubleshoot the code or delete the script. There is now apparent indication that the script exists. How do I track it down to delete it?

Here is the summary from the email:

Summary:

Error Message   Count
ReferenceError: "alert" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code")   13
We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code UNKNOWN.    11